# How to add a enum key that can take have value

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

This is my data class and the enum for the type.

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class MyData(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("type")
    val type: MyTypeEnum? = null,
) : Parcelable
```

```kotlin
enum class MyTypeEnum {
    @SerializedName("tall")
    TALL,

    @SerializedName("short")
    SHORT,
}
```

Having these as responses

Response 1 :

```
{id: "1", title:"New title", type:"middle"}
```

Response 2:

```
{id: "2", title:"Awesome", type:"really_short"}
```

How do I add a new enum to `MyTypeEnum` so that the type for this two response to be `MyTypeEnum.Others`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but I think you can manually implement Parcelable in your enum class to customize its serialization behavior:

```
enum class MyTypeEnum(private val parcelName: String): Parcelable {
    TALL("tall"), 
    SHORT("short"), 
    OTHERS("others");

    override fun describeContents(): Int = 0

    override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        out.writeString(parcelName)
    }

    companion object CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<MyTypeEnum?> {
        override fun createFromParcel(`in`: Parcel): MyTypeEnum? {
            val name = `in`.readString()
            return MyTypeEnum.values()
                .firstOrNull { it.parcelName == name }
                ?: MyTypeEnum.OTHERS
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<MyTypeEnum?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work. Will get `MyData("id"="1", "title"="New title", "type"=null`)